# How to direct spark logs when running in client mode?

Tags: python, apache-spark, client, pyspark, apache-spark-standalone

I am using `pyspark` to run an application on a cluster in `client` mode using `standalone` for monitoring.

All I want to do is see the logs.

I've tried two things:

1)  I went to the config file (`spark-defaults.conf`) in SPARK_HOME:

```
spark.eventLog.dir     hdfs:<ip>:<port>/<path to directory/
```

2)  set in my python script the following:

```
conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.eventLog.dir", 'hdfs:<ip>:<port>/<path to directory/')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Neither of these seem to produce logs in the folder.  Is there anything else that I can try?

Thank you.  this is spark 1.3

Comment: do you want spark logs or spark event logs ?

Comment: oy.  what's the difference?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html - spark event logs is to view webui after your application had run, basically it contains the web ui related metrics. spark logs is the actual application logs.

Comment: based on what i've read - spark logs.  Thank you @Knight71

Comment: If you only want to view the logs, you can head over to the history server - `http://<server-url>:18080/api/v1` and check under`/applications/[base-app-id]/logs`

Comment: That only works if you are using `YARN` or  `MESOS`.  It doesn't work for standalone.  The link provided by @Knight71 provided even says that http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html "If Spark is run on Mesos or YARN,..."